How to Handle Touch Events Going Out of Sync with Render Loop in GameActivity?
I am working on an Android project using the GameActivity template in Android Studio. I've encountered an issue where touch events sometimes go out of sync with the render loop. When this happens, I do not receive any touch events for the current frame, and the missed touch events are instead received in the next frame.
Since I am using the GameActivity template as is, everything else remains unchanged except for the additional logs I am printing.
Main Loop:
void android_main(struct android_app *pApp) {
    // Initial log
    aout << "Welcome to android_main" << std::endl;

    // Register an event handler for Android events
    pApp->onAppCmd = handle_cmd;

    // Set input event filters (set it to NULL if the app wants to process all inputs).
    android_app_set_motion_event_filter(pApp, motion_event_filter_func);

    // This sets up a typical game/event loop. It will run until the app is destroyed.
    do {
        // Start timing the loop
        auto loopStart = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        // Process all pending events before running game logic.
        bool done = false;
        while (!done) {
            // 0 is non-blocking.
            int timeout = 0;
            int events;
            android_poll_source *pSource;
            int result = ALooper_pollOnce(timeout, nullptr, &events,
                                          reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pSource));
            switch (result) {
                case ALOOPER_POLL_TIMEOUT:
                    [[clang::fallthrough]];
                case ALOOPER_POLL_WAKE:
                    // No events occurred before the timeout or explicit wake. Stop checking for events.
                    done = true;
                    break;
                case ALOOPER_EVENT_ERROR:
                    aout << "ALooper_pollOnce returned an error" << std::endl;
                    break;
                case ALOOPER_POLL_CALLBACK:
                    break;
                default:
                    if (pSource) {
                        pSource->process(pApp, pSource);
                    }
            }
        }

        // Check if any user data is associated. This is assigned in handle_cmd
        if (pApp->userData) {
            // We know that our user data is a Renderer, so reinterpret cast it. If you change your
            // user data remember to change it here
            auto *pRenderer = reinterpret_cast<Renderer *>(pApp->userData);

            // Process game input
            pRenderer->handleInput();

            // Render a frame
            pRenderer->render();
        }

        // End timing the loop
        auto loopEnd = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto loopDuration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(loopEnd - loopStart);
        aout << "Render Loop Completed: " << loopDuration.count() << " ms" << std::endl;

    } while (!pApp->destroyRequested);
}

Input Method:
void Renderer::handleInput() {
    // handle all queued inputs
    auto *inputBuffer = android_app_swap_input_buffers(app_);
    if (!inputBuffer) {
        // no inputs yet.
        return;
    }

    // handle motion events (motionEventsCounts can be 0).
    for (auto i = 0; i < inputBuffer->motionEventsCount; i++) {
        auto &motionEvent = inputBuffer->motionEvents[i];
        auto action = motionEvent.action;

        // Find the pointer index, mask and bitshift to turn it into a readable value.
        auto pointerIndex = (action & AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK)
                >> AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        aout << "Pointer(s): ";

        // get the x and y position of this event if it is not ACTION_MOVE.
        auto &pointer = motionEvent.pointers[pointerIndex];
        auto x = GameActivityPointerAxes_getX(&pointer);
        auto y = GameActivityPointerAxes_getY(&pointer);

        // determine the action type and process the event accordingly.
        switch (action & AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_MASK) {
            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_DOWN:
            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                aout << "(" << pointer.id << ", " << x << ", " << y << ") "
                     << "Pointer Down";
                break;

            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_CANCEL:
                // treat the CANCEL as an UP event: doing nothing in the app, except
                // removing the pointer from the cache if pointers are locally saved.
                // code pass through on purpose.
            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_UP:
            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                aout << "(" << pointer.id << ", " << x << ", " << y << ") "
                     << "Pointer Up";
                break;

            case AMOTION_EVENT_ACTION_MOVE:
                // There is no pointer index for ACTION_MOVE, only a snapshot of
                // all active pointers; app needs to cache previous active pointers
                // to figure out which ones are actually moved.
                for (auto index = 0; index < motionEvent.pointerCount; index++) {
                    pointer = motionEvent.pointers[index];
                    x = GameActivityPointerAxes_getX(&pointer);
                    y = GameActivityPointerAxes_getY(&pointer);
                    aout << "(" << pointer.id << ", " << x << ", " << y << ")";

                    if (index != (motionEvent.pointerCount - 1)) aout << ",";
                    aout << " ";
                }
                aout << "Pointer Move";
                break;
            default:
                aout << "Unknown MotionEvent Action: " << action;
        }
        aout << std::endl;
    }
    // clear the motion input count in this buffer for main thread to re-use.
    android_app_clear_motion_events(inputBuffer);

    // handle input key events.
    for (auto i = 0; i < inputBuffer->keyEventsCount; i++) {
        auto &keyEvent = inputBuffer->keyEvents[i];
        aout << "Key: " << keyEvent.keyCode <<" ";
        switch (keyEvent.action) {
            case AKEY_EVENT_ACTION_DOWN:
                aout << "Key Down";
                break;
            case AKEY_EVENT_ACTION_UP:
                aout << "Key Up";
                break;
            case AKEY_EVENT_ACTION_MULTIPLE:
                // Deprecated since Android API level 29.
                aout << "Multiple Key Actions";
                break;
            default:
                aout << "Unknown KeyEvent Action: " << keyEvent.action;
        }
        aout << std::endl;
    }
    // clear the key input count too.
    android_app_clear_key_events(inputBuffer);
}

These are the generated logs:
Pointer(s): (0, 664.549, 1738.64) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 18 ms
Render Loop Completed: 17 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 722.799, 1718.8) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 16 ms
Render Loop Completed: 16 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 772.529, 1693.19) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 18 ms
Render Loop Completed: 17 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 797.65, 1664.94) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 16 ms
Render Loop Completed: 16 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 811.132, 1635.7) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 18 ms
Render Loop Completed: 17 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 819.744, 1601.02) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 16 ms
Render Loop Completed: 16 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 817.596, 1561.57) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 18 ms
Render Loop Completed: 17 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 803.249, 1508.75) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 16 ms
Touch event received: 28 ms
Render Loop Completed: 22 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 780.531, 1457.13) Pointer Move
Pointer(s): (0, 747.079, 1411.89) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 14 ms
Render Loop Completed: 15 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 703.121, 1372.5) Pointer Move
Render Loop Completed: 12 ms
Touch event received: 18 ms
Render Loop Completed: 14 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 655.339, 1341.75) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 17 ms
Render Loop Completed: 19 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 596.977, 1316.59) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 17 ms
Render Loop Completed: 14 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 544.625, 1300.61) Pointer Move
Touch event received: 17 ms
Render Loop Completed: 17 ms
Pointer(s): (0, 484.656, 1295.21) Pointer Move

Any insights, workarounds, or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
My Questions:

How can I fix this synchronization issue?
Is there a way to ensure that touch events are processed in the same frame they are received?

Can I increase the frequency of onTouchEvent without changing the frame rate?
I want to handle touch inputs more frequently without impacting the render loop's frame rate.

Is there an alternative method to receive touch events at a higher rate than the frame rate?
I am looking for ways to decouple the touch event handling from the render loop, possibly processing touch inputs at a much higher frequency.


